# Trying to redirect anything after the full URL without /68 for example

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect

I need to remove anything on the end of URLs like the below examples without the /68 or any number ID

https://www.website.com/forum/making-coffee/68  <-- I would like to remove the / and anything after so it looks like this below.

https://www.website.com/forum/making-coffee

I've searched but can't get the redirect to work correctly.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.+?)/[0-9]+$ /$1
```